# .Net Newton.Json deserialize does not work

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I'm stuck on this issue with deserialization of a json file to a model in my asp.net application.
So I've got a Json file that I get from an api call

```
"Motorola": [
        {
            "id": 534,
            "vendor": "Motorola",
            "type": "mobile_phone",
            "model": "MOTO Z2 FORCE",
            "models": [
                {
                    "condition": "C",
                    "price": 5269,
                    "local_price": 29745,
                    "id": 3407,
                    "memory": "128 GB",
                    "color": "lunar_grey",
                    "product": 534
                },
                {
                    "condition": "D",
                    "price": 4699,
                    "local_price": 26527,
                    "id": 3407,
                    "memory": "128 GB",
                    "color": "lunar_grey",
                    "product": 534
                }
...
```

And three models

```
public class TradeInResponseModel
    {
        public string BrandName { get; set; }
        public List<TradeInBrandResponseModel> ModelsList { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class TradeInBrandResponseModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Vendor { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
        public List<TradeInProductResponseModel> ModelProducts {get;set;}
    }
```

```
public class TradeInProductResponseModel
    {
        public string Condition { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int LocalPrice { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Memory { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
    }
```

But after I run `TradeInResponseModel tradeInResponseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TradeInResponseModel>(responseMessage);`
Where `responseMessage` is a response from an api in form of json file
The model is `null`
Can't figure out what is going wrong here.

Comment: Your JSON has a root object with a single property named `Motorola`, not `BrandName`. If you want to parse this JSON as a dictionary you should use `Dictionary<string,List<TradeInResponseModel>>` as the type

Comment: Copy your JSON text here: https://json2csharp.com/ and you'll get the C# classes you should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON has a root object with a single property named `Motorola`, not `BrandName`.

In JavaScript (and JSON) objects are actually dictionaries. When you tell a serializer to deserialize the JSON data as a specific object it will try to match each dictionary key to an object property.

If you want to parse this JSON as a dictionary you should use `Dictionary<string,List<TradeInResponseModel>>` as the type, eg :

```
var brands=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,List<TradeInResponseModel>>>(
                  responseMessage);
```